# Why is the command 'add-migration' not accepting my installed packages in project.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

After installing the microsoft.entityframework.tools -Pre/ and microsoft.entityframework.sqlserver, when using add-migration "InitialCreate", I have an error stating "build failed". Even when trying to explicitly build the project, it fails.

This is the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OdeToFood, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\Users\Nazaqat\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OdeToFood\src\OdeToFood" --configuration Debug --no-dependencies
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5): error : 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My `Project.json` file looks like this:

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

After looking online, I saw a solution which was to add the following runtime section into the `project.json` file - which makes the solution build successfully:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { }
  }
```

However when using `'add migration "InitialCreate"'` inside the Package Manager Console, I get the error:

```
Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.
```

Even though I have all the installed packages in the above `project.json` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My JSON file changed to one below made my application work. I had to ensure I had the version of the installations below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
    },



  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },


  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: For those wonder what's different, adding `"type": "platform"` to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is the workaround you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update the `frameworks` section to target `netcoreapp1.1`

If that doesn't help replace it with this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.1.0"
      }
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50"
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the framework `1.0` to `1.1` and the result was this: `The specified deps.json [C:\Users\Nazaqat\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OdeToFood\src\OdeToFood\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\OdeToFood.deps.json] does not exist`, and the error message was: `Process finished with non-zero exit code`

Comment: Did you clean the project and then restored NuGet packages?

Comment: Yes. I cleaned the project and built the project again. When I do the "add-migration command, I still get that error of `deps.json` does not exist. `Process finished with non-zero exit code`

Comment: I ran Batch Build and now when I do the "add-migration command, I get this error: `Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.`

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core SDK 1.1? It's the `Current` one on https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: You could also try installing the DotNet tools:
`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Pre`
and running `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` from the command line in the project's folder

Comment: It gives this error `install-package : Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.1.0-preview4-final' uses features that are not supported by the current version of 
NuGet. To upgrade NuGet, see http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget.` even though I have it already.

Comment: Try reinstalling the NuGet extension. 
Also try moving the project to a folder that doesn't contain spaces or dashes in the path

Comment: @AndriySvyryd File is located in location Debug\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64 and that is the problem. Also having same issue. How to solve it?

Comment: I'm getting the same dep.json file not found. I have tried all the answers given. Still get the error.

Comment: @RadenkoZec Remove the "runtimes" section and specify "type": "platform" under "Microsoft.NETCore.App"